# How to do a double integral for a parallelogram?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

[image]

So I found that the Jacobian is equal to $1$. Then I found the bounds and then I found the integral by plugging in $u$ and $v$ for $x$ and $y$ and I integrated this:

$$\int _6^{10}\int _1^3(u+3v)dudv=208.$$

But $208$ is not the correct answer. What part of my setup is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Is wrong the following?$$\int _1^3\int _{6-2 y}^{10-2 y}(x+5 y)dxdy=112$$

Comment: @Raffaele that works too! i was gonna do that way but my teacher wanted me to show work for the way of using the MAP G instead of just doing the classic way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You exchanged the order of integration. $y=v$ ranges from $1\to3$ and $x+2y=u$ ranges from $6\to10$.

Comment: oh my gosh thanks im so stupid

Comment: Nevermind that. You are welcome!